# How do i dynamically add two shapes with text next to each other using action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to add to rectangles to the stage dynamically using action script 3. When I use the code below I only see one shape with text. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Matt

```
var room:Sprite = new Sprite();

var bgBlue:Shape = new Shape() 
bgBlue.graphics.beginFill( 0xCEEDF0);
bgBlue.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, 200, 30 );
bgBlue.graphics.endFill();

var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.color = 0xFFFFFF;
tf.font = "Verdana";
tf.size = 17;
tf.align = "center";

var hd_col1_txt:TextField = new TextField();
hd_col1_txt.text = "Shape 1";
hd_col1_txt.x = 0;
hd_col1_txt.y = 0;
hd_col1_txt.width = bgBlue.width;
hd_col1_txt.setTextFormat( tf );

var hd_col1_shp:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
hd_col1_shp.addChild( bgBlue );
hd_col1_shp.addChild(hd_col1_txt);
room.addChild(hd_col1_shp);
hd_col1_shp.x = room.width;
hd_col1_shp.y = 0;

var hd_col2_txt:TextField = new TextField();
hd_col2_txt.text = "Shape 2";
hd_col2_txt.x = 0;
hd_col2_txt.y = 0;
hd_col2_txt.width = bgBlue.width;
hd_col2_txt.setTextFormat(tf);

var hd_col2_shp:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
hd_col2_shp.addChild( bgBlue );
hd_col2_shp.addChild(hd_col2_txt);
room.addChild(hd_col2_shp);
hd_col2_shp.x = 220;
hd_col2_shp.y = 0;

stage.addChild(room)
```

Answer (score 0):

bgBlue is just one instance, everytime you do

```
.addChild( bgBlue );
```

You are taking that instance and adding it to another parent display object: moving it from one parent to another.

If you are going to have just two shapes, just duplicate the code of bgBlue:

```
var bgBlue2:Shape = new Shape() 
bgBlue2.graphics.beginFill( 0xCEEDF0);
bgBlue2.graphics.drawRect( 0, 0, 200, 30 );
bgBlue2.graphics.endFill();
```

And then add the new shape instead of the original bgBlue

```
hd_col2_shp.addChild( bgBlue2 );
```

Of course, if you are going to have more shapes added should be better to define a class and make instances of it to add the dynamically.

By the way, in your code you have:

```
hd_col1_shp.x = room.width;
```

Be careful, maybe the sprite width is not going to be defined just after adding it to stage

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks a lot that explanation is logical and makes sense with my brief understanding of instances in action script 3.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when a task or a block of code is intended to be used many times, it's better to put it in a [function](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/functions.html) to get a simpler and more maintainable code.

For your case, you want to create buttons, menu items or whatever. So you can write a function which will create one item every time according to data or parameters that you will pass to it ( background color, text color, width, height, ... ).

For that you can start by fixing your items parameters like this :

```
var items:Array = [
    {bgcolor: 0xCEEDF0, width: 200, height: 30, x: 0, y: 0, label: 'Shape 1', color: 0x000090},
    {bgcolor: 0xff9900, width: 200, height: 30, x: 201, y: 0, label: 'Shape 2', color: 0xffffff}
];
```

Then you can write the function that will create the item with its background and label and will be executed for all your items :

```
function create_item_with_label(item_data:Object, items_container:Sprite): void
{   
    var text_format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        // set the color of the text
        text_format.color = item_data.color;
        text_format.font = 'Verdana';
        text_format.size = 17;
        text_format.align = 'center';

    // create the background
    var item_bg:Shape = new Shape();
        item_bg.graphics.beginFill(item_data.bgcolor);
        item_bg.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, item_data.width, item_data.height);
        item_bg.graphics.endFill();

    // create the label
    var item_label:TextField = new TextField();
        item_label.text = item_data.label;
        item_label.x = item_label.y = 0;
        item_label.width = item_bg.width;
        item_label.selectable = false;
        item_label.setTextFormat(text_format);

    var item:Sprite = new Sprite();
        item.x = item_data.x;
        item.y = item_data.y;
        item.addChild(item_bg);
        item.addChild(item_label);

    items_container.addChild(item); 
}
```

Note here that I didn't use a `MovieClip` for the item and instead I used a [`Sprite`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html) because simply we don't need timelines, which is the only difference between these objects.

Then you can create the items container ( the `room` object ) :

```
var room:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(room);
```

And then, you can create your items to be added to your items container :

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    create_item_with_label(items[i], room);
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Sorry for the delay also. I like the idea of using an array makes the generation and modification of properties easier. Still getting a hang of AS3. I also appreciated the first answer because as I hack through AS3 I'm building on concepts. It makes me more confident about more complex manners of completing a task if I better understand the fundamentals. Thanks.